# Plot different graphs one by one in one figure python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, figure

I have 201 data sets from which I want to plot some data. I plot radius in function of velocity and I want to make it visible. Next I want to remove that graph and plot the next one on the same figure. This way a smooth evolution of the graph can be seen. The problem is that every graph is plotted in a new figure, so I just get 201 figures with 201 different graphs as you can see in the image.

[image: image of different figures]

I don't think this is a simulation because the graphs have to be plotted instantly like a normal `plt.plot(…)` (I have tried simulation code) I have tried many different things but they don't work. This is the code I have now. I should probably include some remove type of function somewhere, but I don't know exactly.

```
dynamic = plt.figure()

for j in range(0, 201):
    if j < 10:
       data = pd.read_csv('cout000' + str(j) + '.blk', sep='\s', skiprows=3, 
                          engine='python', header=None)
    elif j >= 10 and j < 100:
       data = pd.read_csv('cout00' + str(j) + '.blk', sep='\s', skiprows=3, 
                          engine='python', header=None)
    else:
       data = pd.read_csv('cout0' + str(j) + '.blk', sep='\s', skiprows=3, 
                          engine='python', header=None)

    velocity = np.array(data[4])*unit_velocity*10**(-5)
    radius = np.array(data[0])*unit_length
    tau_sp = np.array(data[12])

    i = 0
    while np.round(tau_sp[i], 2) != 1.00:
        i += 1

    plt.plot(1 - R_sun_CGS/radius, velocity, 'r-', linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(1 - R_sun_CGS/radius[i], velocity[i], 'ko', linewidth=2)

    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel(r'$1 - \frac{R_{\odot}}{r}$', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel(r'v [km/s]', fontsize=20)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize=20)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe replace `plt.show()` by `plt.pause(num_seconds)`?

Comment: No it didn't work, the different figures with the different plots are just delayed by an amount of time. It would be nice for them to come as fast as possible but in fact the problem is that I want them one by one following each other up on the same figure. That doesn't happen now.

Comment: If you don't call `plt.figure` (or a related function) inside your loop, no new figure should be created.  You can call `plt.clf()` to clear the figure at each iteration (or `plt.cla()` to only clear the plot if that would be sufficient).

Comment: That's what I thought too, but for some reason it doesn't. Also the `plt.clf()` and `plt.cla` don't work either.

Comment: `plt.pause(0.01)` needs to be strictly larger than zero

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Could you clearly describe the problem again? And change the code of the post to show how you incorporated `plt.pause(0.01)`? Preferrably you make the code standalone, with some dummy data instead of reading from file.

Comment: No worries, I tried it again using animation code and it works. Before it didn't work as an animation because I had to import some extra things because I am working in Jupyter Notebook. Thanks for the help